# categories of a section appear of the same order

Tags: joomla

I have the following structure of categories under the `Info-s` section. The latter four categories appear to all have been allocated of the 3rd position. Either changing this number on the admin screen or in the order drop-down inside of the category pages doesn't seem to have any effect.

[image]

I suspect this is due to the way those categories have been created (using the `Copy` functionality).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By deleting and reorganising the section with its respective categories seemed to have fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

try to do it once again after clearing your joomla cache & global check-in in the tool menu in joomla admin back-end

Please update the progress if you need any further help

Comment: Good idea although didn't seem to have any effect on the order level